# Isses with __DIR__ PHP code implementing the wrong home directory

Tags: php

My home directory path is **/home9/** but when I using the `__DIR__` code to get the path, I get **/home/** it's missing the number **9**, I know I can get the path by using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, I just want to know why and how to fix it, I really need to use the `__DIR__` code.

```
<?php
// this is the first code
echo __DIR__ .'<br>'; //I get /home/username/public_html/ is the wrog path

// this the secound code
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; //I get /home9/username/public_html/ the correct path
?>
```

I contacted my hosting provider and they couldn't help, please help.

Comment: Why do you have a directory `/home9/`, with the `9` in it?

Comment: yes that's right @Progman

Comment: The question was **why** you have such a directory. Why did the administrator decided to create such a directory in the root directory (together with the existing `/home/` directory)? Just out of curiosity...

Comment: I don't know really @Progman

Answer (score 1):

These are 2 different things.

Here in your case `/home9/username/public_html/` is symlinked to `/home/username/public_html/` where `/home9/username/public_html/` is the actual document root. However `__DIR__` returns the real path where symlink resolves to.

You can refer php documentation for more information in between these 2.

Comment: I don't thing it does symlinked to /home/username/public_html/ because I'm getting errors in error_log